# Magento Payment methods are not showing in checkout

Tags: payment

I have a website in magento. iam using payment methods paypal, bank transfer and stripe. using multi store view(3)

Except paypal remaning payment methods are not showing in checkout process. i dont know what to do.

please help me any one,

Thanks,

Comment: check if the modules are enabled or nt

Comment: Thansk for your reply.. All are enabled

Answer (score 0):

For me was the usage of an external module with combination of onepage checkout. 
In my case was *Phoenix_CashOnDelivery*  and *Phoenix_BankPayment*